# dynamics crm WBS id order as number

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics

How can I order the tasks in a Project?
I have working on ordering Project tasks. In the Work Breakdown Structure view the WBSid changes as I change the order of the tasks, that is great. in this view the WBSid is right justified and tells me that it is a number. When I add the WBSid to the Project Information view the field is left justified and acts/orders as text.

How can i use the WBSid as a number in a Project Task view to order Project tasks?